# To retrieve a domain's maximum number of users from google apps for business

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-apps

Can we retrieve a domain's maximum number of users, Using google script and OAuth 2.0 or Total purchased licences in a domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `maximumNumberOfUsers` and `currentNumberOfUsers` using the Admin Settings API detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/#retrieving_the_maximum_number_of_users_in_a_domain).